# error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.fastinfoset.FastInfosetSource talend

Tags: java, talend

I am working with Talend version `TOS_MDM-Studio-r118616-V5.5.1` When I try to deploy my model to the server I get the error message:

`org/jvnet/fastinfoset/FastInfosetSource`

And the log shows:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.fastinfoset.FastInfosetSource`

It seems like I am missing a jar file maybe. But, being a total Java newbie I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. Help?

EDITED to include screen shot and error stack trace:

Also, and this may be part of the same issue, when I hit "check connection" nothing comes up, no error, no confirmation it just does not seem to fire.

[image]

STACK TRACE:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86


Error
Fri Sep 26 11:06:25 EDT 2014
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/fastinfoset/FastInfosetSource
at com.amalto.workbench.webservices.XtentisService_Impl.getXtentisPort(Unknown Source)
at com.amalto.workbench.utils.Util.getPort(Unknown Source)
at com.amalto.workbench.utils.Util.getPort(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.workbench.serverexplorer.core.ServerDefService.checkMDMConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.workbench.serverexplorer.core.ServerDefService.checkMDMConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.utils.RepositoryResourceUtil.checkServerConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.widgets.RepositoryViewObjectCheckedWidget.doCheckServerConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.widgets.RepositoryViewObjectCheckedWidget.updateCurrentServerDef(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.dialogs.deploy.DeployAllDialog$2.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2162)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1699)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.dialogs.deploy.DeployAllDialog.initComboSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.dialogs.deploy.DeployAllDialog.createDialogArea(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.actions.DeployAllAction.runWithType(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.ui.actions.DeployAllAction.doRun(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.core.AbstractRepositoryAction$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.repository.RepositoryWorkUnit.executeRun(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.core.repository.model.AbstractRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.repository.localprovider.model.LocalRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.executeRepositoryWorkUnit(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.core.AbstractRepositoryAction.runRWU(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.mdm.repository.core.AbstractRepositoryAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.fastinfoset.FastInfosetSource
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 61 more
```

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your setup and include the full error message please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: I've included the screen shot and stack trace.